# Flutter Firebase Firestore Query Document for field problem

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query documents in a collection and I do this by generating random numbers by creating the documents. I then query for documents with a field that's less than the number. But every time I do that, I get the same document.id which gets me the same DocumentSnapshot. But why?

```
void getRandomfromFirestore1() async {
    int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(9998) + 1;
    print(randomNum.toString());
    final QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("recipes").where("id_created", isLessThanOrEqualTo: randomNum).limit(1).get();
    DocumentSnapshot document = querySnapshot.docs.first;
    final documentID = document.id;
    final DocumentSnapshot data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('recipes').doc(documentID).get();
    print('worked');
    setState(() {
      RecipeTitle = data['title'] as String;
      RecipeTag = data["tag"] as String;
    });
  }
```

In the console, I every time get a different number and the "worked", but when I look at my app, I get the same RecipeTitle and the same RecipeTag every time.

```
I/flutter (30227): 7097
I/flutter (30227): worked
```

//hot restart

```
I/flutter (30227): 291
I/flutter (30227): worked
```

here my firestore: numbers are from 1 to 9999

[image]

[image]

so, in this example, I every time get the rice document

Generally, is there another way to do that?

Comment: You are not using `randomNum` anywhere in your query

Comment: You are right, tried it this way, still not working

Comment: Is there, `rice` and `meat` collection inside of the `recipes` collection? How does it get you the document? And the other question is, if you filter in the firebase console for `recipes` let's say, does it provides you the correct result you want?

Comment: rice and meat aren't collections, they are the documents. I will try it with the recipes filter

Comment: Did it work the recipes filter approach?

Comment: No it doesn't worked

Comment: According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data): `By default, a query retrieves all documents that satisfy the query in ascending order by document ID`.This means that your query is always sorted by the name of the document and not the `id_created`.
I suggest you to try to do an `.orderBy("id_created", "desc")` in order to get different results.